# QT C++ How to properly create functions with Object as Parameters

Tags: c++, qt

I created a class in C++ in which I have a method that receives as a parameter an object of the same class.

I get no errrors on my class definition, however when using the method I get the following error:

```
 error: C2662: 'bool Cliente::igual(const Cliente &)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Cliente' to 'Cliente &'
Conversion loses qualifiers
```

I don´t need to modify the object I send as paramater so I think the best way to go is with references. However I´m pretty new to C++ and any suggestions on what to use (pointers, references, cons references ) will be appreciated.

Cliente.h

```
#ifndef CLIENTE_H
#define CLIENTE_H
#include "qstring.h"

class Cliente
{
public:
    Cliente();
    Cliente(QString,QString,QString);
    QString nombre;
    QString email;
    QString phone;
    bool igual( const Cliente& c);
    const QString getNombre();
    const QString getEmail();
    const QString getPhone();
};

#endif // CLIENTE_H
```

Cliente.cpp

```
#include "cliente.h"
#include "qstring.h"

Cliente::Cliente() {}

Cliente::Cliente(QString n, QString e, QString p){
    nombre = n;
    email = e;
    phone = p;
}

QString const Cliente::getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}
QString const Cliente::getEmail(){
    return email;
}
QString const Cliente::getPhone(){
    return phone;
}
bool Cliente::igual(const Cliente& c){
    Cliente::if(nombre == c.getNombre() && email == c.getEmail() && phone == c.getPhone()){
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage of method:

```
  QList<Cliente> clientList;
    while(query.next()){
        name = QString("A%1").arg(i);
        email = QString("B%1").arg(i);
        phone = QString("C%1").arg(i);
        QString valName = query.value(0).toString();
        QString valEmail = query.value(1).toString();
        QString valPhone = query.value(2).toString();
        Cliente cliente(valName,valEmail,valPhone);
        bool existe = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < clientList.size(); ++j) {
            if (clientList.at(j).igual(cliente)){
                existe = true;
                break;

            }
        }
        if(!existe){
            clientList.append(cliente);
            xlsx.write(name,valName);
            xlsx.write(email,valEmail);
            xlsx.write(phone,valPhone);
        }

        i++;
    }
```

The error happens at: `clientList.at(j).igual(cliente))`

Answer (score 1):

Add getters for `nombre`, `email`, and `phone`.

These getter methods should be `const` methods.

(eg: `QString getNombre() const { return nombre; }`)

Then do the comparison like below

```
if(nombre == c.getNombre() && email == c.getEmail() && phone == c.getPhone()){
    return true;

}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error:

error: C2662: 'QString Cliente::getNombre(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Cliente' to 'Cliente &'
Conversion loses qualifiers

Comment: Which line you get the error? At the getter method or at `Cliente::igual` method? Did you declare newly added `getNomber()` as const?

Comment: I changed the get methods to const but now I get syntax errors on the if statement:
`error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '::'`

I also stil get the original error in the clientList.at(j).igual(cliente) line:

`error: C2662: 'bool Cliente::igual(const Cliente &)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Cliente' to 'Cliente &'
Conversion loses qualifiers`

this is how I have the if statement curently:`if(nombre == c.getNombre() && email == c.getEmail() && phone == c.getPhone()){
        return true;

    }`

Comment: Can you update your question with getter methods you added?

Comment: Don't put `const` in getter implementations in `Cliente.cpp`. Having `const` in header is sufficient.

Comment: Nope :( removing the const in getter implementations This just yields:

 `error: C2373: 'Cliente::getNombre' : redefinition; different type modifiers`

Comment: `const` should be added at the end of the method definition. eg: `QString Cliente::getNombre()  const {`

Comment: Thanks for your helo Lahiru, but this does not solve the problem either. I I get  `error: C2511: 'QString Cliente::getNombre(void) const' : overloaded member function not found in 'Cliente'`

Comment: @PabloEstrada Make sure that the definitions and declarations are identical. You must have the same methods both *defined* and *declared* const!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your getter methods and the comparison should be `const`. You can also implement `operator==`, obviating the need for a method called `igual`.
2. You're including the wrong files. The includes should read:

   ```
   #include <QString>
   ```

   not `"qstring.h"`, even if it happens to work for the particular case of `QString`.
3. Returning a `const QString` is pointless. The `const` there is redundant and has no effect.
4. The data members that the getters are hiding should be made private, or at least protected.
5. `QString` arguments should be passed as const references.
6. Use initializer lists in constructors where appropriate.
7. You can return the comparison result directly, after all it is a boolean.
8. As a matter of style, the getters perhaps should be simply named `foo` instead of `getFoo`.

Taking the above into account, your code should look as follows:

#### Cliente.h

```
#ifndef PABLO_CLIENTE_H
#define PABLO_CLIENTE_H
#include <QString>

class Cliente
{   // The members below are all private.
    QString m_nombre;
    QString m_email;
    QString m_phone;
public:
    Cliente();
    Cliente(const QString &, const QString &, const QString &);
    bool operator==(const Cliente &) const;
    QString nombre() const;
    QString email() const;
    QString phone() const;
};
#endif
```

#### Cliente.cpp

```
#include "Cliente.h"

Cliente::Cliente() {}

Cliente::Cliente(const QString & nombre,
                 const QString & email, const QString & phone) :
  // Initializer list must match the order of member declarations!
  m_nombre(nombre), m_email(email), m_phone(phone)
{}

QString Cliente::nombre() const {
    return m_nombre;
}

QString Cliente::email() const {
    return m_email;
}

QString Cliente::getPhone() const {
    return m_phone;
}

bool Cliente::operator==(const Cliente & c) const {
  return nombre() == c.nombre() && email() == c.email() && phone() == c.phone();
}
```

For simple classes like this one, you could put all the code into the header:

#### Cliente.h (no .cpp!)

```
#ifndef PABLO_CLIENTE_H
#define PABLO_CLIENTE_H
#include <QString>

class Cliente
{   // The members below are all private.
    QString m_nombre;
    QString m_email;
    QString m_phone;
public:
    Cliente() {}
    Cliente(const QString & nombre,
            const QString & email, const QString & phone) :
      // Initializer list must match the order of member declarations!
      m_nombre(nombre), m_email(email), m_phone(phone)
    {}
    bool operator==(const Cliente & c) const {
      return nombre() == c.nombre() && email() == c.email() && phone() == c.phone();
    }
    QString nombre() const { return m_nombre; }
    QString email() const  { return m_email; }
    QString phone() const  { return m_phone; }
};
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wonderingwhats the difference between using #include 'QString.h' and #include <QString>?

Comment: @PabloEstrada The difference is that using `#include "qstring.h"` is undocumented and can break at any point in time. Per documentation, you're *always* supposed to include the class name, or, for some modules, a special name that combines the namespace with function name. Thus `#include <QObject>`, `#include <QString>`, `#include <QMouseEvent>`, `#include <QtConcurrentRun>` etc.